# HOW TO CONVERT ISO8601 TIME AS DATETIME IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

EXAMPLE:

How to convert time

> "2019-08-15T08:48:20.602Z"

as

> "2019-08-15 08:48:20"

in MySQL?

Comment: Use the `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

Comment: How to convert to _what_?  If there is query involved here, can you include it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Actually just use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2019-08-15T08:48:20.602Z",'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s');
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hbmYdPBi1RA3xpLCaqwwan/3